# Device token Changing after exported as ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Hi Everybody i'm working with Apple Push Notifications for my app here i'm struggled with Device token issues & not getting Notifications.

i successfully created a .p12 key then i uploaded in Amazon SNS it working good and i'm receiving notifications also.

**ISSUE** Not getting notifications for exported ipa.

When i run with xcode it giving some device token(ex. xxx1111).after i uninstalled the old one,i exported as ipa,& uploaded in diawi.com then run it in same device it gives some different device token(ex. yyy2222). now i copied that new device token(yyy2222) into Amazon SNS with same .p12 key only, now i'm not getting any notifications.

But i deleted the app installed from diawi.com again i run it from xcode then i send the notifications with old device token(xxx1111) it getting notifications.

what is my mistake? help me pls.

Comment: What is problem with your `app`, `.p12` or `amazon SNS` that I didn’t figure out…but please note that once you receive device token then it will remain same during application’s life in device. Every time you reinstalled app, token will be changed.

Comment: app , apns  & AMAZON SNS is fine.i deployed the app from xcode app getting notification but exported ipa file then i'm not getting notifications for same .p12key only i,m using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** You've probably not uploaded the production APN certificate to your APN provider.

If the version of the app you run from Xcode works, but the exported version does not, then maybe you've only set up the development APN certificate in your APN provider. The exported app (be it Ad Hoc or Enterprise) is going to use a production certificate, so your APN certificate should be production too.

If you haven't created the production certificate, go to `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` in the developer portal, click on `Production` and choose `Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)`:

[image: Production APN Certificate]

p.s. The token *should* change between development and distribution versions of the app.

Comment: thanks for your reply.For distribution i want to create Separate .p12 key?

Comment: sorry, I meant to say "production" not "distribution". yes, you probably want to create a separate p12 file. I added some more info on the steps to take in the developer portal.

Comment: thank u now it working. but i had another issue also. i check this by Amazon SNS it working then i fixed in my java Project to send notification it not working.. but developer p12 key worked in java project

Comment: in my java project i referd https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns  ApnsService service =
    APNS.newService()
    .withCert("/path/to/certificate.p12", "MyCertPassword")
    .withSandboxDestination()
    .build();   String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("Can't be simpler than this!").build();
String token = "fedfbcfb....";
service.push(token, payload);

Comment: Do either of development or production APNs work in your java app? For production shouldn't that be `withProductionDestination()` instead of `withSandboxDestination()`?